# how to arduino project compile with maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

i am working now on [Ardunio](http://www.arduino.cc/) project and i want to use [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to compile and run my project .
how could i to configure pom.xml file to be able to compile project

Answer (score 0):

See this example

https://github.com/dukeboard/kevoree-extra/tree/master/org.kevoree.extra.avr-arduino.nix

Look for the other projects:
https://github.com/dukeboard/kevoree-extra

I personally have not tested